# Change layout dynamically in DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-dialog

I want to use a Dialog to allow the user to scan its device for all the files with a certain extension and import some of them.

To do that, I plan to show a dialog, which will have the following behaviour:

1. While I scan the SD card, the dialog will show a progress bar and one TextView with the path of the last file found.
2. After scanning all the SD card, I will show a list in the same dialog with all the files found. The user will select some of them (with checkboxes) and click on "Import" or "Cancel".

**I'm wondering what's the best strategy to implement this?**

I can think of two possibilites:

- Use two fragments (one for each one of the steps explained above),
  and switch the Fragment when the scan finishes. So far I couldn'ẗ
  find how to switch a Fragment inside a Dialog.
- Use one Fragment and change the Layout dinamically. This means having a single layout with both functionalities, and show or hide them alternatively (with `View.VISIBLE` and `View.GONE`). I prefer the other option because here I will inflate some view that won't be shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Display a ListView into your DialogFragment and use an emptyView for the progress.
Implement a Loader to scan for your Files. When the loader finished the work simply use an Adapter for your ListView and the Empty View will disappear automatically.